# Automate the build of dwproj using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

Is it possible to automate the build of `.DWPROJ` extensions with `msbuild` instead of `devenv`. I am facing few licensing problems with building the solution using `devenv`

My current approach is as follows

```
function BuildCube($SlnFileName, $SlnFilePath)
{    
    $parameters = """$SlnFilePath"" /Build"
    $vsPath= (Get-Item  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe').GetValue($name)
    Start-Process -FilePath $vsPath -ArgumentList $parameters -Wait      
    Write-Progress -Id 20275 -Activity $SlnFileName  -Status "Done building." -PercentComplete 100;
}
```

Exception I got when trying with msbuild
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just calling msbuild instead of devenv (and change $parameters to just ""$SlnFilePath"")?

Comment: I doubt that msbuild will not build dwproj

Comment: Fair enough, but did you try? What error do you get?

Comment: Attached the image when I tried with msbuild

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately running msbuild on this type of project is not supported so far. According to Microsoft this feature is on schedule:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11536152-support-ssas-ssis-ssrs-in-msbuild

So far only hacks like building project with devenv.exe on command line are posssible:

http://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2014/automate-build-and-deployment-of-ssas-cubes-using-msbuild/